# Javascript construct trap not working in class returning proxy

Tags: javascript, oop, metaprogramming, es6-proxy

I am trying to create a little javascript two way form binder using proxies. I am stuck on how I can intercept 'new' calls. I use a 'construct' trap but it doesn't fire. Here is my code, I have removed the stuff that is not relivant for my specific problem

```js
    class BoundObject {

        constructor(object, element) {

            // distribute object properties into "this"
            for (const prop in object) {
                this[prop] = object[prop]
            }

            return new Proxy(this, {

                construct:(target, args) => {
                    console.log(`Creating a new ${target.name}`) // why is this not fired?
                    return Reflect.construct(...args)
                },
                set: (target, prop, val, receiver) => {
                    console.log(`attempting to set ${prop}=${val} type ${typeof val}`);

                    return Reflect.set(target, prop, val) 
                }
            })
        }
    }

    // create an instance of our BoundObject class, passing in an object and an HTML element
    const user = new BoundObject({name:'fred'},document.querySelector('#user-form'))    // why is the 'construct' call not intercepted?
    user.name = 'mary' // set user name. The 'set' call is sucessfully intercepted
```

The `set` trap works, but the `construct` trap fails to fire.  I suspect this is to do with javascript deep magic around 'this' but cannot figure it out

How can I intercept the construction of the proxy object my class returns?

Comment: You're returning the Proxy instance from your "BoundObject" constructor. When do you expect the "construct" trap to be fired? You're code is already in the actual class constructor; the code is not going to jump into the returned Proxy code.

Comment: Nothing is invoking `new user` (which is impossible since it's not a constructor anyway), so the `construct` trap doesn't fire on it either.

Comment: "*How can I intercept the construction of the proxy object?*" - why would you need to "intercept" that? Just put the code that you want to run on construction in the constructor of your class.

Comment: @kiwichris ... In addition, a class-constructor never ever should return anything else than an instance of its own type. Anything different than that should be returned by a factory function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `construct` trap is only called when the `[[Construct]]` internal method is invoked on the **proxy itself**. This could be caused by using the `new` operator. However, in this case, the Proxy is returned as a result of calling `new` on the `BoundObject` constructor; `new` was not called on the proxy itself.

Here is an example of where the `construct` trap could be called.

```js
function MyObj() {}
const proxy = new Proxy(MyObj, {
  construct(target, args) {
    console.log(args);
    return new target(...args);
  }
});
new proxy('something');
```

Comment: thank you.  I was getting confused between the 'BoundObject' constructor, and the proxy object returned by the BoundObject constructor